# Developer account in OSX, admin or managed user with our without sudo access?

Tags: programming-practices, security

The tutorials I find to setup OS-X for web developer programming (installing x-code ruby js cocoapods sql c asm etc) leave out if it should be done from an admin account, or standard (managed) user.

Some methods I've seen used: Setup dev environment from admin account, then change admin to managed user. Or install dev environment from managed user, using sudo or otherwise editing settings to get things to install.

What's the consensus for using Terminal from a managed & parental controlled account? What's the correct procedural way to setup a fresh 10.10 install? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't work with Ruby, but I work with Django/Python and I think the same principles apply.

Don't install stuff system-wide. To give you an idea, these are different methods for installing Python packages, from worst to best:

- `sudo pip install django`: install Django system-wide. Don't do this.
- `pip install --user django`: install Django for current user only. Better, but not great.
- `virtualenv --distribute myproject; . myproject/bin/activate; pip install django`: create a `virtualenv` and install Django in there. Best. Multiple web projects can exist, each using different versions of Django, different versions of dependencies, as needed

You get the idea. The equivalent must exist for Ruby on Rails too.

As much as possible, install everything in user space.

Some things won't really be practical this way, 
for example a MySQL database or Apache web server.
It depends on how much modularity you need.
If you will never ever need isolated MySQL servers running,
then you can just install one and isolate uses by separating MySQL user accounts.

The most professional option is probably to work in sandboxes,
using software such as Vagrant or Docker.